# Solving modified version of the Partition problem

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics

So I am looking at a problem which is similar in principle to computing partitions for a large N. My problem is similar to the following hypothetical problem.

Let's say that I have a random variable X which has possible outcomes of 1,2,..., 10, each of which occurs with corresponding probabilities P1,P2,...,P10. My hypothetical problem: if I generate 20 random and independent samples of X and sum them together, what is the likelihood of the resulting summations of 10,11,12,... 200.

A few approaches which occurred to me which are workable-in-theory but computationally-not-close-to-possible are as follows.

Idea 1) List out the partitions of 200. Remove any partition categories which use a number greater than 10. Calculate the probabilities of each and sum up for each sum (sum = 10,11,...,200). This is ezpz for small N, completely and totally bonkers for 'huge in this context' N like 200.

Idea 2) List out all the possible 20 item sample results (ie 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2,1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2,etc), note the probability of each, and sum up for each sum (sum = 10, 11, ... , 200). Again, ezpz for small N, completely infeasible in this context.

I also had the following idea, but I was not able to get it to work.
Idea 3) Modify your favorite 'generate the partitions' algorithm so that any number greater than 10 cannot be used in a partition. Similar to Idea 1 in principle, however we generate a small list and don't have to trim down a huge list. My two issues with this idea, a) I am not sure how to do this for any partition generation algorithm, and b) even if I could I am not convinced it would be computationally feasible.

Any points on how I can tackle this? At the end of the day it is similar to any host of other problems in the bucket of [enumerate all possible outcomes, compute the probability of each, aggregate the probabilities for each aggregate sum, and you have your answer]. However the sample space is so huge.

This would be really easy to approximate via monte carlo, but that approach leaves a bad taste in my mouth as so many of the theoretically possible outcomes will not show up, even 10 billion+ iterations or so.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

[I am flexible on the language of choice, but I have a bias towards using Python where possible]

Comment: Could you do Idea 2, but iteratively? Start by computing the sample space and corresponding probability distribution for 2 independent samples.  Then calculate the sum of that distribution with one more sample from your initial distribution, and so on.  At each stage the sample space (number of sums) only grows linearly, and the number of combinations to compute is only 10x the size of the previous sample space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a recursive solution based on the idea in Aaron's comment. This uses the solution for previous values of N to find larger values of N.

Unlike the other answer, this method is not an approximation.

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
probs = [0.1] * 10
Distribution = namedtuple('Distribution', 'numbers probs')


def find_prob(dist, n=1):
    if n == 0:
        # If you draw 0 numbers, you have a 100% change of getting zero.
        return Distribution([0], [1])
    else:
        # Find probability of each number, drawing one fewer sample
        dist_b = find_prob(dist, n - 1)
        # Combine two distributions. Add up all probabilities for getting
        # the same number.
        prob_for_num = defaultdict(float)
        for a, p_a in zip(dist.numbers, dist.probs):
            for b, p_b in zip(dist_b.numbers, dist_b.probs):
                num = a + b
                # Probability of p(A&B) = p(A) * p(B)
                prob = p_a * p_b
                prob_for_num[num] += prob

        # Split numbers and probabilities into two lists
        numbers, probs = zip(*prob_for_num.items())
        return Distribution(numbers=numbers, probs=probs)
sol = find_prob(Distribution(numbers=numbers, probs=probs), 20)
```

I set this up in a simple way, with each number 1 through 10 having equal probability. The numbers don't have to be consecutive, though, and the probabilities don't need to be equal. I just did that for the sake of simplicity.

It can easily sum up with N=20. It starts to slow down at around N=1000. If you want to sum up more samples than this, you may want to look into more efficient methods of recursion.

When I sum up 20 samples of a uniform distribution, I get this graph of probabilities:

[image: normal distribution]

...which is the normal distribution, as expected.

Comment: Nick this solution is amazingly fast, thank you so much! I will kick the tires further but after some trial runs the results look spot on. A huge thanks for sharign your expertise!

Answer (score 1):

randomly generate 100000, and count each value apparend.If you want specific value, use binomial distribution.
Here is a python simulation:

```
def random_int_by_probas_sum(probas_cum, r):
    """
    @param probas_cum cumulation probablities of the 10 random numbers.
    @param r random number
    return the value of r-percentage. for example r=0.3, it will return 3, r=0.8, it will return 8
    """
    for index in range(len(probas_cum)):
        if r <= probas_cum[index]:
            return index

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

nums = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
#
probas = [0.05, 0.15, 0.07, 0.13, 0.09, 0.11, 0.08, 0.12, 0.04, 0.16]
probas_cum = [0.05, 0.2, 0.27, 0.4, 0.49, 0.6, 0.68, 0.8, 0.84, 1]
random_count = 1000000
sums = []

for _ in range(random_count):
    sum_step = 0
    for i in range(10):
        r = random.random()
        sum_step += random_int_by_probas_sum(probas_cum, r)
    sums.append(sum_step)

sums = pd.Series(sums)
sums.value_counts()
```